# Plot data with different length

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that looks like this:

```
Country Sales Year    
Germany 2000  2000
Germany 1500  2001
Germany 2150  2002
UK      1200  2000
UK      1300  2001
UK      2000  2002
Japan   500   2000
Japan   750   2001
```

I want to plot the data for each country and year wrt the sales value. For this purpose I use `ggplot` with `geom_line()`. The problem is that line for `Japan` goes down to 0 for the `year` 2002 since there is no data for `Japan` that year. What I want to do is just to stop all lines in the data at 2001 that do not represent a `value`, rather than seeing the dropping down to 0 in 2002.

edit:
My code below. Note that I also have a vector for the size of the lines that i want to use in the real data, just remove `scale_size` and `size` to get rid of that.

```
ggplot(df_Filtered, aes(x = Year, y = Sales, colour = Country, scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1), size=mysize)) +  geom_line() +
    labs(x = paste("Sales per country"), y = "Sales per country", title = NULL) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2000, 2001, 2002)) + 
    scale_size(range = c(1, 4), guide="none") +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank())
ggsave(paste("Output/", "Sales", ".png", sep = ""), width=20, height=11, limitsize = FALSE)
```

Comment: That sounds bizarre. Can you share you `ggplot` code and verify that your sample data demonstrates the problem? ggplot doesn't usually plot points that aren't in the data... when I import your data and do `ggplot(dd, aes(x = Year, y = Sales, color = Country)) + geom_line()` everything looks normal.

Comment: Well, as stated, ggplot should not give you problem about it, however you can do this  `df %>% filter(Year <2002) %>% ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(Year), y=Sales))+...`, with `dplyr` package, however it's way better to look at your code.

Comment: Posted the code. In the real data I have a bit more stuff (I have a data set with 500 000 rows), but I adjusted the example in the code to make it easier.

Comment: Why is `scale_y_continuous` inside of `aes`?

Comment: I don't know, I think that might be an error. When I do plot this it works fine, which it does not with the real data I have. Then the line for one country just drops to 0. it is the exact same code, just other data...

Comment: No it does not. It is all my fault. I got a few countries in my huge data set that actually have sales values very close to 0 in the data. That is why it looks like the graph goes down to 0, even if that is not the case. All my bad. Ty for helping me anyway - thanks to this I noticed the problem with my data, rather than with my code.

Comment: Yes, this is yet another reason it is always good to make a reproducible example. Often in creating the example you find the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I am new to R so I still have things to learn. Thanks to stackoverflow I am at least making progress. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this code? My graph, shown below, does not have Japan's `geom_line` falling to zero.

```
df_Filtered <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
     Country = c("Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "UK", "UK", "UK", "Japan",
                 "Japan"),
       Sales = c(2000L, 1500L, 2150L, 1200L, 1300L, 2000L, 500L, 750L),
        Year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2000L, 2001L)
)

mysize <- 0.1

ggplot(df_Filtered, aes(x = Year, y = Sales, colour = Country, scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1), size=mysize)) +  geom_line() +
  labs(x = paste("Sales per country"), y = "Sales per country", title = NULL) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2000, 2001, 2002)) + 
  scale_size(range = c(1, 4), guide="none") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem with values close to zero that I might want to get rid of!