# Different colour palettes for different series ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a continuation of this problem: [Plot data with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704343/plot-data-with-different-length)

I have data that looks like this in a df I call `df_Filtered`:

```
Country Region  Sales Year    
Germany Berlin  2000  2000
Germany Hamburg 1500  2001
Germany Kiel    2150  2002
UK      London  1200  2000
UK      York    1300  2001
UK      Leeds   2000  2002
Japan   Tokyo   500   2000
Japan   Kyoto   750   2001
```

I want to plot the data for each region and year wrt the sales value:

```
ggplot(df_Filtered, aes(x = Year, y = Sales, colour = Country,
                        scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1), size = mysize)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(x = paste("Sales per country"), y = "Sales per country", title = NULL) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2000, 2001, 2002)) + 
    scale_size(range = c(1, 4), guide = "none") +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank())

ggsave(paste("Output/", "Sales", ".png", sep = ""), width = 20, height = 11,
       limitsize = FALSE)
```

Note that I also have a vector for the size of the lines that i want to use in the real data. In the real code the lines representing the average country value is thicker, but to make it simple:

```
Size = 2
df_Filtered$mysize <- rep(Size, nrow(df_Filtered))
```

My question now is how do I assign a colour pattern to each country? That is, when I plot the Japanese regions I want the lines for the regions to get different red colours, when I plot the German once I want it to be black etc. I also want one line for each series (the one that is thicker) to be in the middle of the palett. For Japan that means that one line should be red and the other once dark and light red.

Is there any way to do this without manually having to assign each region a colour value manually?

Comment: The basic design in ggplot only allows you to map each aesthetic ones. See e.g. Hadley's answer here [Multiple fill scales with seperate legends](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/lDvsd4yJ0AE). Various work-arounds are therefore needed.

Comment: I did this manually and made an Excel file with the hex codes. However, I get the problem that when I put `colour = Colour` (the row in `df_Filtered` where I have the hex codes), I get the colour codes in the description box below the graph instead of the regions. How do I solve this?

Comment: The easiest way to do this would probably be to use map country to `color`, and map whatever variable distinguishes among lines within one country to `alpha`. Altering the transparency using `alpha` would give you light, medium, and dark shades of a color without resorting to overly complex workarounds.

Comment: That is interesting, I will try a manual one first but if that does not turn out to give me a good result I will try that one.