# Assign colours in ggplot from a manual value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a df, `df_Filtered`, that looks like this:

```
Country Region  Sales Year Colour   
Germany Berlin  2000  2000 #FF0000
Germany Hamburg 1500  2001 #33CC33
Germany Kiel    2150  2002 #00FF00
UK      London  1200  2000 #CC0000
UK      York    1300  2001 #FFFF33
UK      Leeds   2000  2002 #339900
Japan   Tokyo   500   2000 #66CC00
Japan   Kyoto   750   2001 #990099
```

I want to plot the data for each region and year wrt the sales value:

```
ggplot(df_Filtered, aes(x = Year, y = Sales, colour = Region, scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1), size=mysize, labels=as.matrix(df_Filtered_regions))) +  geom_line() +
    labs(x = "Years", y = "Sales", title = NULL) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2000, 2001, 2002)) + 
    scale_size(range = c(1, 4), guide="none") +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + 
    theme(legend.position="bottom") +
    scale_color_discrete(name=NULL) +
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 1)) +
    theme(axis.line = element_line())
```

Note that I also have a vector for the size of the lines that I want to use in the real data. In the real code the lines representing the average country value is thicker, but to make it simple:

```
Size = 2
df_Filtered$mysize <- rep(Size, nrow(df_Filtered))
```

I want to use the colours from the column `Colour` in `df_Filtered` for the lines in the plot. How do I do this?

(I previously tried to assign the colors a by an automatic process, but that did not work out very well: [Different colour palettes for different series ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715695/different-colour-palettes-for-different-series-ggplot) )

Comment: the first line in the ggplot2 code block is malformed. Why is the scale function call in the ggplot2 function call? what is `df_Filtered_Cancer_regions`? why are you using a matrix for labels (and why is that in the aes when there's not text geom?)? As it stands, your example is not reproducible.

Comment: Sry, changed the lbl-code. As for the rest, I know it is a mess - that is why I came here. I got stuck on trying to manually assign the colors and messed up my code...

Comment: `df_Filtered_regions` also does not exist.

Comment: Yeah, I am new to R and messed everything up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make an effort in future questions to provide working code, esp since the ggplot2 construct is seriously incorrect in many, many places. I also strongly suggest you do not use the colors you've chosen for the final plot. Finally, decimal ascii code character 32 (i.e " ") is free and I suspect adopting and adhering to a code format style would help avoid some of the plot construct errors in the future.

You can use pre-generated geom-component colors using `I()` which marks the column "`asis`" which informs ggplot2 to just use the values specified.

```
library(ggplot2)

read.csv(text="Country,Region,Sales,Year,Colour
Germany,Berlin,2000,2000,#FF0000
Germany,Hamburg,1500,2001,#33CC33
Germany,Kiel,2150,2002,#00FF00
UK,London,1200,2000,#CC0000
UK,York,1300,2001,#FFFF33
UK,Leeds,2000,2002,#339900
Japan,Tokyo,500,2000,#66CC00
Japan,Kyoto,750,2001,#990099", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) -> xdf

xdf$mysize <- rep(2, nrow(xdf))

ggplot(xdf) +  
  geom_line(
    aes(
      x = Year, y = Sales, group = Country,
      colour = I(Colour), size = mysize
    )
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2000, 2001, 2002)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1) +
  scale_size(range = c(1, 4), guide = "none") +
  labs(x = "Years", y = "Sales", title = NULL) + 
  theme(axis.line = element_line()) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

ggplot2 plotting idioms get easier to grok as you use them. Practice is essential.

You want a legend, but you didn't work through how to use a manual color scale. We'll build a named vector from the data you specified:

```
manual_scale_colors <- setNames(xdf$Colour, xdf$Region)
```

then remove the `I()` and add back the manual scale call:

```
ggplot(xdf) +  
  geom_line(
    aes(
      x = Year, y = Sales, group = Country,
      colour = Region, size = mysize
    )
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2000, 2001, 2002)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = manual_scale_colors) +
  scale_size(range = c(1, 4), guide = "none") +
  labs(x = "Years", y = "Sales", title = NULL) + 
  theme(axis.line = element_line()) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: This one works fine, thanks a lot! You also cleaned up my code. Just one more question: if I want to have the legend in the figure, how do I add it? I tried to get it to the bottom by adding `theme(legend.position = "bottom")`

Comment: You have to do _alot_ of work to make a legend when you use "asis" colors. Also, SO is not a "code cleaning" service. You're new here, but it's expected that posters make some type of effort to provide a readable, working example.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will try to make better code next time.

Comment: The answer has been updated to show how use the built-in color scale function so you can get the desired result.

Comment: Great, thanks! I tried a few hours yesterday and failed (and messed up my code trying). I guess "practice is essential" is the key here.

Comment: What about using `scale_color_identity`? That should do all this automagically, no?

Comment: Aye, but there's a great deal of nuance in utilizing these aesthetics. The OP really should not be pre-generating colors for this use-case IMO and for production chart work at $DAYJOB I often have a proper color scale for categorical data but also have another geom for various annotations or clarifications where the `I()` comes in handy (since you can't have more than one color or fill scale (yet) in ggplto2), so I (for the most part) tend to not advocate the use of color/fill identity scale aesthetics unless one is, say, getting a data set with color data already in it.

Comment: Having said that, you should def make that another answer (it's a proper/valid suggestion that folks might not know abt).